# Sum the numeric value of cells in a row, but only if they include a specific alpha value

Tags: excel, equation

I am generating a spreadsheet for a local non-profit that will be used to track sick leave and vacation time. The main data entry page is a calendar that has a row, per month, per employee. This yields a row of cells containing value combinations of the following kinds; `V1`, `JD1`, `V.5`, `S1`, `S.5`. These represent the type of time used (V, JD, S, P) and if it is a full or half day off(1, .5).

I would like to create a separate equation for each value, that would check each cell in a range for that value and include only the days with that value and sum them.

How do I check a cell for a specific alpha variable, before including its numeric value in the containing equation's mathematics?

[image]

Comment: Pleas give us an example of a few lines. It would make it easier.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, it must be done this way. The main data entry page needs to make sense to the end user.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=41595A0FA3017A6D!10758&authkey=!AF8rA1W6qSpjcTU&ithint=file%2cPNG

Comment: In your picture "JD" is only "J".  Are all the prefixes only one character?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a 1 letter prefix then this would work:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(RIGHT($B11:$AF11,LEN($B11:$AF11)-1),0)*1)
```

For the first line in January, adjust the ranges to suit.

If more than it is a little more hairy:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($B11:$AF11),"S",""),"P",""),"V",""),"JD","")*1,0))
```

For every other option one must put another substitute function to deal with it.

These are Array formulas ans must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

If you want each separate then:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($B11:$AF11),"JD","")*1,0))
=SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($B11:$AF11),"S","")*1,0))
...
```

And so forth

If your report is setup as such:

[image]

Then you can use the following array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet6!$A$11:$A$30=$A2)*(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(Sheet6!$B11:$AF30),B$1,""),0)))
```

Put in B2, hit ctrl-shift-return.  Then copy across and down.  It will display the totals per. Where Sheet6 is the name of the sheet on which the data is located.

Comment: @pnuts I think I covered everything now.

Comment: @pnuts typo when changing to match the OP data set.  Mine was a lot smaller.

Comment: @pnuts  It's late, I will use that as my excuse. The `I` in F1 I got from C2 in the OP's picture. There is a lot of disconnect between the verbal description and the photo. I chose the photo to be more accurate.